# PHP - trying to sort an array by a numeric field

Tags: php

I have an array of data comprising a 'customer' and a 'Total'. (example below). It is drawn from two different databases.

I need a way to sort the array, based on the Total field, so that the Largest Total is at the top. But so far every thing I have tried has resulted in it assuming that 5 is larger than 32
[5, 32, 25, 16, 11]

What's the easiest way to achieve this? I tried adding intval() to the strcmp function, but it made no difference?

```
$arrayName = array();

$arrayName[] = array ('customer' => 'Customer1', 'Total' => 25);
$arrayName[] = array ('customer' => 'Customer2', 'Total' => 16);
$arrayName[] = array ('customer' => 'Customer3', 'Total' => 32);
$arrayName[] = array ('customer' => 'Customer4', 'Total' => 5);
$arrayName[] = array ('customer' => 'Customer5', 'Total' => 11);

print_r($arrayName);
print "</br>";

//Sort the Arrray by Total
function arrSort1($b, $a)
{
    return strcmp($a['Total']), $b['Total']);
};

usort($arrayName, "arrSort1");

print_r($arrayName);
```

Comment: "5" *is* larger than "32" when compared *lexically*. Why `strcmp` for numbers?!

Comment: I never thought of it like that, good point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing by string but you really want to compare by numeric value.  Try:

```
function arrSort1($b, $a)
{
    if ($a['Total'] > $b['Total']) {
        return 1;
    } else if ($a['Total'] < $b['Total']) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The sorted array will look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [customer] => Customer3
            [Total] => 32
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [customer] => Customer1
            [Total] => 25
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [customer] => Customer2
            [Total] => 16
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [customer] => Customer5
            [Total] => 11
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [customer] => Customer4
            [Total] => 5
        )

)
```

Comment: `>` → `-`, `$cmp` needs to return an `int`.

Comment: @deceze I'm not sure I follow, returning whether or not one is larger than the other sorts the array by `Total` in descending order. You can make it ascending by changing `>` to `<`.

Comment: The comparison function must return *"a value `< 0`, `0` or `> 0` depending whether the first value is smaller than, equal to or greater than the second."* A `bool` won't do exactly the same thing.

Comment: cheers, simply changing the 'return' line has fixed it.

Comment: @deceze You're right, now that I think about it I normally use an if/then. I updated the answer.

Comment: `$a['Total'] - $b['Total']` will do just fine as well.

Comment: @deceze yeah nice, now I see what you mean.